# In a LotusScript Agent how do you get the name of the current server?

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus, lotusscript

In a LotusScript Agent that is being run via WebQueryOpen, how do you get the name of the current server?

Answer (score 5):

```
Set s = New NotesSession
Set db = s.CurrentDatabase

If db.Server <> "" Then
  Set sName = New NotesName(db.Server)
Else
  Set sName = New NotesName(s.Username)
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

The sample code already provided is good but I also do it this way and just get the hierarchical name of the server:

```
Set s = New NotesSession
Set db = s.CurrentDatabase
If db.Server <> "" Then
   Set sName = New NotesName(db.Server)
Else
   Set sName = New NotesName(s.Username)
End If
ServerName = sName.Abbreviated
```

Answer (score 0):

Gary's answer is the most appropriate. You can actually identify the server name using hierarchical syntax to.

```
dim session as new notesSession
dim strCurrServer as string
dim nmServer as notesName

strCurrServer = session.currentagent.servername
' this bit is optional 
set nmServer = new notesName(strCurrServer)
' then you can do stuff like this
print nmServer.Abbreviated
```

That would be the fastest (dirtiest?) way to get the server name from the webquery open agent. The notesName class is a handy object for dealing with hierarchical names
[link text](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESNAME_CLASS.html)

Answer (score -3):

```
'initialize event of a WebQueryOpen agent

Dim s As New notessession   
Dim servername As String
servername = s.UserName
```

Comment: `s.UserName` is not reliable: the code may be running as a web user, or under a special signing Notes ID< in which case you wouldn't be getting the actual server name from this call.